# Error when loading module in Python: OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python

I have installed a PyMultiNest package and I am trying to access PyCuba which is a part of this package.

When importing it, I keep getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vdthomas/Documents/BENEFIT/Asymptotic Delta/Formulas/MCAR rho neq 0/brouillon.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pycuba
  File "C:\Users\vdthomas\anaconda3\envs\MCAR rho neq 0\lib\site-packages\pycuba\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libcuba.so')
  File "C:\Users\vdthomas\anaconda3\envs\MCAR rho neq 0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\vdthomas\anaconda3\envs\MCAR rho neq 0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I have been searching around and apparently this error code is very frequent and is related to the path to, and/or presence of, the dll file.

I have only very basic notions of programming, so I have very naive questions: what is the dll file? How do I identify it/find it's location?

If the file is indeed missing, what are the actions to solve this problem?

Comment: DLL stands for "dynamic loadable library" or something like that. It's compiled, machine-executable code (for the most part, and this discussion) that is needed for the python module to work. And it seems your packaged needs some. Have you followed the instructions here: https://johannesbuchner.github.io/PyMultiNest/install#building-the-libraries ? This suggests one has to build libraries their own. And it only talks about Unix. Are you sure you can work on windows?

Comment: Thank you! They suggest installing the cuba library in order to get the libcuba.so file (which, it seems, is causing the problem). I do have it installed, but it doesn't seem to arrange things. I'll go on searching, but you did give me a good hint what to look for :)

Comment: A .so-File is the Linux variant of a DLL. In other words: this does NOT work on Windows. You will have to change your platform, e.g by using a (free) virtual machine with linux on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'libcuba.so' is a DLL file for Linux, not for Windows. Please make sure you installed distribution for Windows, not the Linux one.

Comment: Do you know it exists for windows? Evidence points not towards that.

Comment: @deets I don't know. Probably it should be built from sources.

Comment: I think there is no version for windows. I'm trying to figure things out using virtual linux terminal, but having never used linux, it is going to be a challenge. Thank you both for all thee help.

Comment: @Vaiva.D If you are running the Virtual Linux environment based on 16.04, you may simply want to install corresponding package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cuba. However, in this case you have to install Anaconda under this virtual linux environment. From the logs you provided I guess you have Windows Anaconda setup.